# Django Rest Framework - DELETE ajax call failure due to incorrect CSFR token

Tags: ajax, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I'm trying to use the django rest framework to to easily handle some models as restful resources. 
this is the code that I have:

```
Django: 1.7.1

Django REST Framework: 2.4.4

jQuery: 2.1.1

# models.py

class DocumentNodeTemplate(MPTTModel):
    """

    """
    document_template = models.ForeignKey(
        DocumentTemplate,
        related_name="nodes",
        verbose_name="Document template"
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='children'
    )
    section_template = models.ForeignKey(
        'SectionTemplate',
        related_name="node_templates",
        verbose_name="Section template"
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.section_template.name

    def get_class(self):
        type = self.section_template.type
        return import_string(type)


# serializers.py

class DocumentNodeTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentNodeTemplate
        fields = ('document_template', 'parent', 'section_template')


# views.py

class DocumentNodeTemplateAPIView(CreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = DocumentNodeTemplate.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentNodeTemplateSerializer


<!-- HTML (section - admin's change form customization)-->
<fieldset class="module aligned">
    <h2>{{ node_fieldset_title }}</h2>
    <div class="form-row document-nodes">
        <div
        style="width: 100%; min-height: 450px;" id="general-container"
        data-document_model="{{ document_model }}"
        >
            <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
                <div id="tree-container">
                    <div id="tree"
                         data-url="{{ tree_json_url }}"
                         data-save_state="{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}"
                         data-auto_open="{{ tree_auto_open }}"
                         data-autoescape="{{ autoescape }}"
                            >
                    </div>
                    <div class="add-node">
                        <a href="/admin/document/{{ model_name }}/add/?_to_field=id&document_id={{ object_id }}" class="add-another"
                            onclick="return showCustomAddAnotherPopup(event, this);">
                            <img src="/sitestatic/admin/img/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10"
                                 alt="Add another node"> Add another node
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class='node-custom-menu'>
                        <li data-action="delete">Delete node</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="node-container">
                <h3 id="node-name"></h3>
                <br/>

                <div id="node-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>


// javascript 
var performCRUDaction = function(action, api_url, callback) {
var csfrtoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').prop('value');
var _reloadNodeTree = function () {
    window.nodeTree.tree('reload');
}
var _performAction = function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: actionType,
            url: api_url,
            data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csfrtoken },
            success: function () {
                console.log("action " + action + " successfully performed on resource " + api_url);
                _reloadNodeTree();
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("action " + action + " failed on resource " + api_url);
            }
        });
    }


    var actionType,
        documentModel = null;
    var nodeDataObj = {};
    switch (action) {
        case "delete":
            actionType = "DELETE";
            break;
        case "update":
            actionType = "PUT";
            break;
        case "create":
            actionType = "POST";
            break;
        case "retrieve":
            actionType = "GET";
            break;
    }
    _performAction();
    callback();
}
```

I didn't posted all the code, anyway when that ajax call is triggered, I obtain a 403 error:

```
// headers

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8050
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8050/api/documentnodetemplates/46
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:403 FORBIDDEN
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,it;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:52
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:djdt=hide; sessionid=x5cw6zfifdene2p7h0r0tbtpkaq7zshq; csrftoken=NyMqLlKxeeAdc4Eq2nFpFOebh0SUBBVY
Host:127.0.0.1:8050
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8050
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8050/admin/document/documenttemplate/1/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken:NyMqLlKxeeAdc4Eq2nFpFOebh0SUBBVY
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
csrfmiddlewaretoken:NyMqLlKxeeAdc4Eq2nFpFOebh0SUBBVY
Response Headersview source
Allow:GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 20 Nov 2014 09:52:31 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
Vary:Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

// response
{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

Anybody experienced the same or similar problem and can help?

Thanks
LuKe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete all your Cookies and other site and plug-in data and Cached images and files by going into history tab and then clear browsing data...ANother option is to use @csrf_exempt decorator with your class based views..

Comment: cache is disabled since i'm using chrome with Dev tooolbar open, I can check again flushing history. using `@csrf_exempt` is not a solution since it removes CSFR protection

Comment: so why dont you try incognito window ?

Comment: no way. tried with firefox witn cleaned history, same result

Comment: Luck , What was the problem?