# Django Rest Framework requesting authentication on AllowAny setting

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-1.6

I've created a [JWT-Authorised](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) back end for an app.  Login, logout, token retrieval and refresh all work fine, and as expected.  I added a registration view this morning, which is throwing the usual `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided.` error you'd expect for non-authenticated requests, as that's the default (see below).

However, because this is a registration endpoint, I don't want it to only allow authorised requests.  (Having checked with a valid token, the rest of the view works as expected when you supply authentication.) Looking at the permissions section of the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), I thought that using the permission_classes wrapper with AllowAny would work here, but it hasn't.

What am I missing? I feel like the permission_classes decorator should override the default setting of 'IsAuthenticated'?

I'm testing on localhost from curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email":"boba@athingy09876.com", "first_name": "boba", "last_name": "fett" "password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8000/account/register/
```

View is:

```
@permission_classes(AllowAny)
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_user(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Response ({"already_registered": "User with that username has already registered"}, status=status.HTTP_701_ALREADY_REGISTERED)
    data = request.data

    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=data["email"],
                                               email=data["email"],
                                               first_name=data["first_name"],
                                               last_name=data["last_name"],
                                               password=data["password"])
    if created:
        token = obtain_jwt_token(data["email"],data["password"] )
        return Response ({"token": token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response ({"already_registered": "User with that username has already registered"}, status=status.HTTP_701_ALREADY_REGISTERED)
```

Permissions in settings.py are:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Related questions: 
[Django Rest Framework - Authentication credentials were not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided) - I think the default permissions are correct, I just want to override them in this instance.

[Django Rest Framework - DELETE ajax call failure due to incorrect CSFR token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036881/django-rest-framework-delete-ajax-call-failure-due-to-incorrect-csfr-token) - CSRF not being used as JWT Based auth.

[Django: Rest Framework authenticate header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877249/django-rest-framework-authenticate-header) - Apache specific issue (currently still on devserver localhost)

[Django Rest Framework Authentication credentials were not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043310/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided) - Not yet answered!

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hey!  I haven't had a chance to implement it yet, but it looks good - i'll get to it tomorrow, before the bounty expires. :) Sorry about the delay!

Comment: Totally unclear as to why the question's being voted down, btw - if there's a problem with the question, then do let me know, it's not like it was a half-baked, unresearched question.

Answer (score 6):

The order of the decorators matter. There's also some problems with your code.

I recommend using a serializer, maybe something like below. If you want to use emails as username, I would make a custom User model. Django's default authentication system's username field has max_length of 30, and people's email addresses easily surpass that.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny,])
def register_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Response({"already_registered": "User with that username has already registered"}, status=701)
    data = request.data
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(username=serializer.validated_data['email'])
        token = #call the url to get your tokens, use urllib or something similar
        return Response({"token": token}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Edit**
The ordering of decorators goes like this:

```
@decorator
@decorator2
def func():
    print('hello world')
```

Is the same as decorator(decorator2(func)))

Comment: Oh man.  I changed the order of the decorators, and boom, there you go.  I couldn't get the serialized version to work off the bat, but I can see what you mean, so I'll have a crack at redoing it that way tomorrow using this as a jumping off point.  Thanks!    Any ideas where would I look to find out more about ordering decorators like this?

Comment: added something about decorators... tried putting here but the code looked horrendous on the comments...

Answer (score 4):

You have disabled permissions using `@permission_classes`, but that's only the "authorization" part of "authentication and authorization". You need to disable [the authentication handlers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) as well using `@authentication_classes` in order to stop receiving a 401/403 error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. From reading that, suggests that when the auth fails as expected it should provide an AnonymousUser at request.user - but according to the permissions stuff, it shouldn't matter, @permission_classes(AllowAny) should allow unrestricted access.  In any case, I've tried with @authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)) to no avail, and can't see anything in restframework.authentication that covers this use case - do I need to extend the baseclass for this? Seems overkill... (As in, I'm mostly sure I just don't understand)

Comment: I've also gone in and set
`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    }` 
Which seems to work, but now I have to wrap every other function in explicit decorators, rather than using the default behaviour, which seems a bit backwards? Surely there's a (clearer?) way to disable the auth handlers.  I've been through the docs you linked several times and I just don't see it. :(

Answer (score 0):

*in views*

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
```

and use this in class based view or function based view

```
authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
```

for example

```
class CreateProduct(generics.CreateAPIView):
authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
queryset = Product.objects.all()
serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
```