# JWT authentication doesn't work for custom controller in Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, json-web-token

I am using the Django Rest Framework in my Python app, and am using JSON Web Token Authentication (DRF JWT) for the api authentication.

My problem comes when I am building a custom controller. I pointed a specific URL to a function in my `calculations.py` file that I created. Following are how they look.

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers 
from app.serializers import xxxViewSet, yyyViewSet
from app.calculations import getReturns

router  = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"xxx", xxxViewSet)
router.register(r"yyy", yyyViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^api/auth/token/$', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
url(r'^api/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
url(r'^api-token-verify/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.verify_jwt_token'),
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
**url(r'^getReturns/', getReturns),**
)
```

`calculations.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import xxx, yyy, zzz, aaa

def getReturns(request):
    data = request.GET('data')

    **running calculations here on data and giving out response**

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

`serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets, permissions
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from .models import xxx, yyy, zzz, aaa

class xxxSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = xxx
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class xxxViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser]
    queryset = xxx.objects.all()
    serializer_class = xxxSerializer
```

The above `serializers.py` file contains serializer classes for all my models, and also viewsets for the same. I haven't yet transferred the viewsets into `views.py`, so that file is empty for now.

Anyway, my `calculations.py`is separate from these files, and the function defined in this file is directly being called by the '/getReturns/' URL without going through a view. How do I incorporate the functions defined in my calculations file into a viewset so that my authorization classes are called before the function gets executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started doing this in comments and it was too long. Generally, you haven't really provided enough code to assist properly, but here's my crack anyway.  It's not obvious which version/implementation of Django JWT you're using (there are a few), how you're authorising your views, or whether your calculations.py file is a view or something else.  (If it's something else, I'd authorise in the view, and call it from there.)

Why are you unable to send a POST?  Generally, Once you have the token in your front end, you can use `from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes` and `@authentication_classes([JSONWebTokenAuthentication,])` wrapper on any function that needs authorisation.

That looks like this:

```
@authentication_classes([JSONWebTokenAuthentication,])
def function_here(arguments):
    #function does stuff
```

How are you passing/trying to send the web token back to the application?

Presumably in CURL your initial auth to get a token looks something like: 
`curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=abc123`
after that you get (if you're using `rest_framework_jwt`) the token back:
`{JWTAuthorization: YourTokenHere}`.

After that, to return it to DRF protected pages (assuming they're wrapped, as above, or have a similar protection) - you haven't outlined how you're authorisation - [then from the docs you do](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage):
`curl -H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>" http://localhost:8000/protected-url/`

If you're generating the call in Angular or similar, then it's the same - you need to pass it in the headers.

Edit: I'd also note you've drastically increased the amount of code here since my original answer.  Fundamentally though, you need to check the auth classes you're declaring; the easiest way is as specified above.

Comment: I can see now that I have not provided all the required information. I am using this for JWT https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt. `calculations.py` contains only that one single function that I have put down in the question `getReturns`. I did not wrap it inside any view. As you can see in the `url.py` file, I am simply calling this function and attaching it to the URL. Should I put this into a view in my `views.py`? If so how do I do this and set it up with the authentication?

Comment: I edited the question. Could you take a look at it now and respond?

Comment: The answer is still the same, you need to use the @authentication classes wrapper on the function, it's in my answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example. The getblimp docs are fairly good though, I'd have another read of them, they include everything I've said here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have gone through the docs, but got a little confused in this section. But yes, I will go through them again. I will mark this answer as correct as soon as I get this to work. Also, can I include `@permission_classes` in the same way?

Comment: Yep. :) the order of the wrappers is important - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29330430/1293222